# function to add user to ldap server from php work but no user add

Tags: php, ldap

- the connection to server is working
- the user data is present
- the `$r= ldap_add($connect, $base_dn, $info)` have no result false or true;

```
public function insert(User $user) {    

    //First: Connect to  LDAP Server
    $connect = ldap_connect( $this->dao->host(), $this->dao->port());       
    ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    $ldap_user  = "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com";
    $ldap_pass = "root";

    //Login to LDAP
    $bind =  ldap_bind($connect, $ldap_user, $ldap_pass);

    // Adding new user 

    if ($connect) {

    $base_dn = '"cn='.$user['realname'].', dc=example, dc=com"';        

      // Prépare les données
        $info["cn"] = $user['realname'];
        $info["username"] = $user['username'];  
        $info["mail"] = $user['email'];     
        $info["objectclass"] = "person";                

    // Ajoute les données au dossier
    $r = ldap_add($connect, $base_dn, $info);             

        ldap_close($connect);

    } else {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Impossible de se connecter au serveur LDAP'); 
    }       
}
```

Comment: Stop assuming success. ldap_add() returns true/false, and you never check that. you need `if (!$r) { die(ldap_error()); }` or similar.

Comment: the given error after adding your code is:  Malformed JSON data (Webos.Error): Empty response. Data :